# Using COM from a R script

Tags: r, com, activexobject

I woud like to be able to start and call a COM object from within a R script (in Windows obviously). There is a library called RDCOM http://www.omegahat.net/RDCOMClient/ but

1. it does not support VARIANT data types - and the COM object
   expects VARIANT as parameters and returns arrays in them
2. is it maintained? are there active alternatives?

What I need to call is a function defined like this in the .idl file (the idl file gets compiled to create a COM object - not important except if you want to know the exact deeclaration of the object)

```
[id(3), helpstring("method GetQuestionList")] HRESULT GetQuestionList([out] VARIANT* nQuestionCount,[out] VARIANT* arrNames, [out] VARIANT* arrIndents, [out] VARIANT* arrTypes);
```

In this method the fields are passed by reference - in VB you would call it like this

```
        Dim myObject = CreateObject("AskiaAPI.Analyse")
        Dim arrIndents, nQuestionCount, arrNames, arrTypes As Object
        myObject.GetQuestionList(nQuestionCount, arrNames, arrIndents, arrTypes)

        Dim nQuestion 
        For nQuestion = 0 To nQuestionCount - 1
            lstResults.Items.Add(nQuestion & ": " & arrNames(nQuestion))
        Next nQuestion
```

In the code above, the variables nQuestionCount, arrNames, arrIndents, arrTypes are initialised by GetQuestionList (that's why they are passed by reference). In that example, lstResults would be a ListBox used to display the content of one of the parameters.

Any hint or idea is welcome!

Comment: Please show what you intend to do. Unlike VBA which requires `Dim` to declare variables and maintains the *variant* data type, R does not need declaration of data types.

Comment: I need to call a proprietary COM object... this object has methods like this one where fields are passed by reference : [id(3), helpstring("method GetQuestionList")] HRESULT GetQuestionList([out] VARIANT* nQuestionCount,[out]  VARIANT* arrNames, [out]  VARIANT* arrIndents, [out]  VARIANT* arrTypes);... I want to call that method and read the contents of the variables...

Comment: Please post this in the body of your post, very difficult to read. See *edit* link. And also post links to this COM object's tutorial or its VBA example.

Comment: I have updated the body - thanks!

Comment: What is that first code line? What is an .idl file? How does that connect to the lower VBA lines. And where in code are these variables assigned values: *arrIndents*, *nQuestionCount*, *arrNames*, *arrTypes*? And what is *myObject* or *lstResults*? This is difficult to follow. We need a fully compilable code block not snippets. Generally, most VBA code (which itself COM connects) can be translated to RDOMClient.

Comment: Updated body again - hoping it's clearer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147712/discussion-between-badjerry-and-parfait).